# Cannot configure optional Owned Type

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**Money (Value Object)**

Encapsulates a decimal value.

```cs
public class Money
{
    public decimal Value { get; init; }
}
```

**NetAndTax (Value Object)**

Encapsulates Net Amount (Money), Tax Amount (Money) and Id of the Tax Rate used.

Both Tax Amount and Tax Rate are optional.  Only Net is required.

```cs
public class NetAndTax
{
    public Money Net { get; init; }
    public TaxRateId? TaxRateId { get; init; }
    public Money? Tax { get; init; }
}
```

**AddOn (Entity)**

The AddOn will relate to an existing `ProductVariant` and will either derive price from that ProductVariant (i.e. FixedPrice will be null) or will have a FixedPrice that will override the price of the related ProductVariant.

```cs
public class AddOn
{
    public ProductVariantId ProductVariantId { get; private set; }
    public NetAndTax? FixedPrice { get; private set; }
}
```

Given the requirements:

- FixedPrice can be null.
- If FixedPrice is present then Net cannot be null, but TaxRateId and Tax can be null

I have tried the following **configuration**:

```cs
public class AddOnMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AddOn>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AddOn> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsOne<NetAndTax>(p => p.FixedPrice, b =>
        {
            b.OwnsOne<Money>(p => p.Net, b =>
            {
                b.Property(p => p.Value).HasColumnName("Net").HasColumnType("decimal(12,2)").IsRequired();
            }).Navigation(p => p.Net).IsRequired();
            b.Property(p => p.TaxRateId).HasColumnName("TaxRateId").IsRequired(false);
            b.OwnsOne<Money>(p => p.Tax, b =>
            {
                b.Property(p => p.Value).HasColumnName("Tax").HasColumnType("decimal(12,2)").IsRequired();
            }).Navigation(p => p.Tax).IsRequired(false);
        }).Navigation(p => p.FixedPrice).IsRequired(false);
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the above should be saying:

1. The navigation property FixedPrice is optional.
2. If FixedPrice is provided, however, then
   a) the navigation property Net is required.
   b) The TaxRateId is optional
   c) the navigation property Tax is optional, but if provided, then Tax.Value is required.

However I am getting the following error:

> Entity type 'AddOn.FixedPrice#NetAndTax' is an optional dependent
> using table sharing and containing other dependents without any
> required non shared property to identify whether the entity exists. If
> all nullable properties contain a null value in database then an
> object instance won't be created in the query causing nested
> dependent's values to be lost. Add a required property to create
> instances with null values for other properties or mark the incoming
> navigation as required to always create an instance.

**Is there a way to configure my owned types as per the requirements?**